# Passing variable from JS to PHP within the same page

Tags: javascript, php

I know this has been answered many times but what i am looking for is the passing of variables within the same page. I understand that PHP is a server side script while JS is the client side thus when the page loads, it will load PHP before JS thus it is impossible to do so.

What i am seeking is an alternative method to perform my JS task which is to take the value after the ? in the address bar (//localhost/Task/delete.php?ID=1). Else alternatively is there a way around passing the variable into PHP as the value will be used to execute a SQL query.

Thanks

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
var url = window.location.href;
var params = url.split('?ID=');
var fdf = (params[1])
alert(fdf);

</script>

<?php
$random = $_GET["fdf"];

echo $random;
?>
```

Comment: You appear to be using the data from the address bar, in JS, already. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Both PHP and JS do not share *"Page"*, therefore there is not such thing as *"JS To PHP within the same page"*. Most likely you're looking for AJAX.

Comment: I assume you're looking for an **[Ajax](https://www.google.com/search?q=submit+a+form+with+ajax)** solution.

Comment: The question is asking to read data from the address bar in JS. There shouldn't be any need to involve PHP (or HTTP and thus Ajax) at all.

Comment: Or if the goal it to read it in PHP, then there is no need to involve JavaScript at all.

Comment: The issue is i have no idea how to code the reading of address bar and splitting in PHP. The reason why i need the variable to be in PHP is because my SQL connections and scripts are in PHP. I would really appreciate if you guys not mark me down for something i have already acknowledge might not work when all i am looking for is a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = window.location.href;
var params = url.split('?ID=');
var id = (params[1]);
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"page.php",
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(result){
        $("#content").html(result);
        }
        });
   });
```

**PHP Code:** page.php

```
<?php
$random = $_POST["id"];
echo $random;
?>
```

**Complete One page code:** demo.php

**Note:** URL for this page must be `demo.php?ID=someValue`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = window.location.href;
var params = url.split('?ID=');
var id = (params[1]);
     $("#submit").click(function(){ $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"demo.php",
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(result){
        $("#content").html(result);
        $("#submit").hide();
        }
        });
        });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="submit">Click Me</button>
<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
<?php
$random = $_POST["id"];
echo $random;
?>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to include jquery library file

Comment: It's utterly pointless to make a request (including a query string) to PHP, have PHP send some JavaScript to the browser, have that JavaScript read the query string (that was already sent to PHP) and send it back to PHP.

Comment: @Quentin Please check the updated code for **Complete one page code**

Comment: @mrdeveloper Thanks for the work around my problem mrdeveloper. Really appreciate your help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The question, despite all the JS in it, appears to be asking:

> Given a URL like `//localhost/Task/delete.php?ID=1`, how can I read the value of `ID` in `delete.php`?

The answer is:

```
$_GET['ID']
```

The relevant section of the manual is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).